# Two inputs with form-control in one input group (bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to insert two inputs into a input group, like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" size="10" class="form-control" title="Username" style="width: 117px;" autocomplete="off">   
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" size="10" class="form-control" title="Password" style="width: 117px;" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 0px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="./viewtopic.php?f=2">
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" data-original-title="" title="" data-style="zoom-in"></input>
            </span> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/gzuktbzd/

But the bootstrap debugger sais, that iits not valid:
https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E010

So how can I solve that?

Comment: have you considered just using an inline-form instead? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Comment: Yes I did, but the input group is part of a form horizonal, so I cannt use that :/

Comment: In short, the answer to your question is "No". Bootstrap doesn't like it. Anyway, it can be done, if you just don't care. But, to properly answer, please give us more code (the entire form could be useful). It can be done, in some ways, but all depends on what your <form> looks like :)